# Very soon clicking causes script malfunction

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made here a form and While the textarea is still expanding and i immediately click on the submit button:

- The textarea doesn't hide but instead go back and animate to
  `height:46px`
- if i click on the submit button again: `(w/o refreshing)

  - the loading image loads.
  - the textarea,submit button and loading image hides.
  - the data returned by the ajax is not displayed

The code is syntactically correct right, How can i possibly fix this?

Jquery:

```
$('.btn').hide();
$('.submitline').submit(function(){
    var $content = $('textarea').val();
    $('.btn').fadeOut('fast',function(){
        $('textarea').fadeOut('fast');
        $('.submitbusy').fadeIn('fast');
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/submit',
        timeout: 15000,
        data: {
            'content': $content,
            'token': fuel_csrf_token()
        },
        success: function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
            $('.submitbusy').fadeOut('fast',function(){
                $('.submitstatus').text(data).fadeIn('fast',function(){
                    $('.submitstatus').delay(2000).fadeOut('fast',function(){
                        $('textarea').val('Submit Another?').fadeIn();
                    });
                });
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
$('textarea').focus(function(){
    $('.btn').fadeIn('fast');
    $(this).val('').animate({"height":"100px"});
    $(this).focusout(function(){
        $(this).animate({"height":"46px"});
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form class="submitline" method="post">        
    <label>Message:</label><input class="btn" name="" value="Submit" type="submit" id="form_" />
    <textarea class="sidesub" name="" id="form_"></textarea>   
      <img class="submitbusy" src="http://i.imgur.com/GaSgz.gif" alt="" />    
</form>
<p class="submitstatus"></p>
```

Comment: Agreed; what's the output on the JS console of your browser? Which browsers have you tried this in? Is the result the same?

Comment: Can you describe the malfunction? If you'd try to fix my car and I'd say "my car isn't working" and you cant test the car, could you fix it? The more information, the better.

Comment: i've elaborated it more, the javascript is loaded in the footer (after the form). @Quentin .My browser's console outputs no error with the code.

Comment: Does it send the ajax request on the first click?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this around your code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // Your code...
}
```

**Update**

Try moving `$.ajax({` before the animation.

Comment: The script is loaded in the footer (after the form) so i suppose i don't need that, right? @PiTheNumber

Answer (score 0):

Make the submit button disabled and add a script (placed last in the HTML file) that activates it.